# embedded excel mobile view

Tags: html, excel

I have an embedded excel in my website. I want to autofit the size for the mobile site. At the moment the size remains to big for mobile screen. How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

```
<center><iframe width="1000" height="800" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="https://onedrive.live.com/embed?resid='Dashboard'!A1%3AL18&wdHideGridlines=True&wdInConfigurator=True"></iframe></center>
```

Comment: How big do you want the spreadsheet to be? The whole width and height?

Comment: Yes the whole width and height (sames cells visible) if possible

Answer (score 1):

To make an iframe the full width and the full height of the viewport, ensure that the `html` and `body` are set to the full `height` and `width` of `100%`. After that is done, you can set the `height` and `width` of the iframe also to `100%`.

```css
html, body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

iframe{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    
    <iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="https://onedrive.live.com/embed?resid='Dashboard'!A1%3AL18&wdHideGridlines=True&wdInConfigurator=True"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

I have tested this code and it works in mobile, tablet and desktop view.